# Getline only read the first row ( or first line)

Tags: c++

my code:

```
string mess;    
getline(cin,mess);
```

and my txt file:

```
hello james\n
how are \n
you.
```

when i am using getline. it just read in hello james. Is there a way that i can read "how are you"?

Comment: Yes, by calling `getline` again.  As its name indicates, it reads one line at a time and your file has two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell `std::getline()` to read up to a specific character. Assuming the character isn't in the stream, it will read the entire stream, e.g.

```
std::string mess;
if (std::getline(std::cin, mess, '\0')) {
    // ...
}
else {
    std::cout << "ERROR: failed to read input\n";
}
```

If you need to read in exactly two lines, you'll probably best of using `std::getline()` twice and combining the result, probably with an intervening `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are open for other ways to solve the problem or if you have restrictions so that you need to use `getline` to read the whole file. If not I find this a nifty way to put the contents of a text-file in memory to process it further.

```
ifstream ifs (filename, ios::in);
if (!ifs.is_open()) { // couldn't read file.. probably want to handle it.
    return;
}
string my_string((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
ifs.close();
```

now you should have the whole file in the variable `my_string`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to read the entire file you can use the function `read()` (See reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/))

```
std::ifstream f (...);

// get length of file:
f.seekg (0, f.end);
int length = f.tellg();
f.seekg (0, f.beg);

char * buffer = new char [length];

// read data as a block:
f.read (buffer,length);
```

If you wish to read just those 2 lines, then its easier to use `getline` twice.